# How to streaming live video from iOS to Flash Media Server

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to streaming live video from `iPhone` to `Flash Media Server`.
Do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Refer following links for iOS. You will get idea how to move forward. Hope it helps you.

1.http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-streaming.html

2.http://www.adobe.com/products/amazon-web-services.html

3.http://www.wowza.com/